# getting 0 output instead of correct output

Tags: java

I can put the input but in output, I got a result of zero. I am using two class one is main which is logbook and another one is grade calculation. In grade calculator, I have written method and constructor and in logbook, class calling those methods through the constructor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LogBook  { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GradeCalculation g = new GradeCalculation();
        g.Askmarks();
        g.finalmark();
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalculation {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    private double quiz, midsemester, appliedproject, finaltest, finalmarks;

    GradeCalculation(double quiz, double midsemester, double appliedproject, double finaltest, double finalmarks){
    }

    GradeCalculation(){

    }

    public void Askmarks(){
        System.out.print("Enter the QUIZ marks: ");
        double quiz = kb.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the midsemester marks: "); 
        double midsemester = kb.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the appliedproject: ");
        double appliedproject = kb.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the finaltest: ");  
        double finaltest = kb.nextDouble();
    }

    public void finalmark(){
        finalmarks= 0.1*(quiz)+0.2*(midsemester)+0.4*(appliedproject)+0.3*(finaltest);
        System.out.print("Enter the final: " + finalmarks);  
    }   
}
```

Comment: You never initialize your fields (i.e. `this.quiz`, etc.) anywhere. All you're doing in AskMarks (which should be named askMarks) is initializing *local* variables which has the same name as the fields

Comment: You're shadowing your fields in `AskMarks()`. :)

Comment: thanks for solving this, have a good one mate

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you were defining **local variables** in `Askmarks`

```
double quiz = kb.nextDouble();
...
double finaltest = kb.nextDouble();
```

They don't affect **the fields**

```
private double quiz, midsemester ,appliedproject ,finaltest,finalmarks;
```

and, therefore, in `finalmark`, you are getting the default value for each `double` field, which is `0.0`.

The solution would be **setting the fields** rather than **initializing local variables**.

```
this.quiz = kb.nextDouble();
...
this.finaltest = kb.nextDouble();
```

Comment: @aNKY, it would be great if you click the checkmark on this answer, since you find that this answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Askmarks` method, you are redefining the variables by prefacing them with `double`. If you remove the `doubles` from your `Askmarks` method, it should work.

```java
public void Askmarks(){
    System.out.print("Enter the QUIZ marks: ");
    quiz = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the midsemester marks: "); 
    midsemester = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the appliedproject: ");
    appliedproject = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the finaltest: ");  
    finaltest = kb.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing your fields in `GradeCalculation` in `Askmarks()`. Remove the type declarations of the variables inside the function. So, instead of:

```
...
double quiz = kb.nextDouble();
...
```

You should use:

```
...
quiz = kb.nextDouble();
...
```

or

```
...
this.quiz = kb.nextDouble();
...
```

---

What you are doing with:

```
...
double quiz = kb.nextDouble();
...
double midsemester = kb.nextDouble();
...
```

is that you are **shadowing** the class fields with the same name (e.g. `double quiz` is going to shadow the class's `quiz`). Shadowing refers to the behaviour in which a variable declared and/or initialized within some scope "replaces" another variable of the same name residing in an outer scope.

In your case, `Askmarks()` will now think that, for example, `quiz` is a local variable that only exists inside the function, and the class field `quiz` no longer exists in its viewpoint.

Comment: Actually, there is no shadowing here, OP didn't refer to any local variables after their initialization

Comment: I don't think you have to refer to any local variables before shadowing can occur. Shadowing has already occurred since the OP has defined local variables with the same name as the instance variables.

Comment: I completely agree with "double quiz **is going to shadow** the class's quiz". I am just saying that defining a variable with a narrower scope and ignoring it doesn't make shadowing kick in. So, technically there is no shadowing/hiding in the OP's snippet.